# I need help fixing a code trying to find substring in a string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a new string and write month names to it, then use it to check if I have already written the month name to a file. This is my code I’m trying to fix:

```
void writeToFile(RainStruct rainPerMonth[], int monthsInYear)
{
   // Create string variable
   string month;
  
   // Create and open file
   fstream rainFile("scramble.txt", ios::out);
  
   // Write into file, goes through each structure and writes it
   for (int count = 0; count < 11; count++)
   {
      // Set random number variable
      int randNum = rand() % 12;
  
      // Set string variable month to different random month names
      month += rainPerMonth[randNum].monthNames;
  
      // Call to checkMonth
      if (checkMonth(rainPerMonth, monthsInYear, randNum, month))
      {
         // Write months in random order to file
         rainFile << rainPerMonth[randNum].monthNames << " had " << rainPerMonth[randNum].monthRain    << " inches.\n";
      }
   }
  
    // Close, reopen, truncate, and close file again
    rainFile.close();
    rainFile.open("scramble.txt", ios::trunc);
    rainFile.close();
}

bool checkMonth(RainStruct rainPerMonth[], int monthsInYear, int randNum, string month)
{
    size_t pos = month.find(rainPerMonth[randNum].monthNames);
    if(pos != string::npos)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

It ends up printing some months twice, and doesn't print all months. What do I need to change to fix it to write all months to a file in random order (with their rain per month attached)?
This is my full code: https://onlinegdb.com/ry6yO4a4_
The specifications of the assignment is that I have to use a string variable to search for a substring inside a string, then check that it’s not already there, then write the month to the file. He said I have to use a random generator and cannot hard code. This is the hint he gave us: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: CAn you show us the struct `RainStruct`? But also, if you run 11 times `rainPerMonth[randNum]` , `randNum` might repeat values , which explains the doubled (or in general, repeated) written months

Comment: Could you show us a fragment of the output file? is the " had " actually being written?

Comment: you could also use a vector of your struct, which would make it a lot easier to handle and you could use [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) to get the random order you search

Comment: Not related to your question , but  `checkMonth` receives several parameters and only uses one

Comment: Also off-topic, but important -- you should indent your code in a coherent manner, so that the program is easier to read.  Right now you have every single line of code flushed to the left margin, making it difficult to know where functions, `for` loops, etc. begin and end.

Comment: please show a [mre] but `month.find(rainPerMonth[randNum].monthNames)` is unlikely to be correct

Comment: Hey Ivan, I'm super new to C++ and this site so I'm still trying to figure it out. I'm not sure how to add anything to my post yet and unfortunately I have to go to work. Posting this was like my last ditch effort of fixing the program (I have to turn it in before midnight). The structure has just two members, months and rainfall, and I put it into an array of structures for each month of the year

Comment: Basically the teacher hinted I needed to use a random generator for the months to be written, and I should use a string variable that I append as I go and then check. He gave this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Here is my code: https://onlinegdb.com/ry6yO4a4_

Comment: @Erin -- If there is a bug in your code, turn off the random number generator and hard code the values.  It makes no sense to try to debug a program that changes every time you run the program.  Once you fix the bug, then turn the random number generator on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the example from `shuffle()` function's [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/shuffle) to create a shuffled list of the month indexes and *then* write it out to the file. `rand()` doesn't guarantee unique indexes so it might return any number between `[0, 11]`, probably even repeating them.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
 
void print(const auto& a) {
    for (const auto e : a) { std::cout << e << ' '; }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
 
int main()
{
    std::array a{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    print(a);
 
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
 
    for (int i{}; i != 3; ++i) {
        std::ranges::shuffle(a, gen);
        print(a);
    }
    //Then just use a[0], a[1]...as the index to rainPerMonth[] and write it out to file
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/6f5haYTn4):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
10 4 6 7 8 11 2 5 9 1 3 0 
0 5 7 4 2 8 11 9 6 1 10 3 
10 8 5 7 9 4 2 6 11 1 3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes most of what you need without adding more dependencies (although std's vectors and arrays are great):

```
struct RainStruct{
    RainStruct(std::string monthNames, int monthRain){
        this->monthNames = monthNames;
        this->monthRain = monthRain;
        }
    std::string monthNames;
    int monthRain;
    };
    
// Shuffle array
void shuffle_array(int arr[], int n)
{
 
    // To obtain a time-based seed
    unsigned seed = 0;
 
    // Shuffling our array
    shuffle(arr, arr + n,
            std::default_random_engine(seed));
 
    // Printing our array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;  // you wont need this
}

void writeToFile(RainStruct rainPerMonth[], int monthsInYear)
{
// Create integers array
int nums[12] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
shuffle_array(nums, 12);

for (int count = 0; count < 12; count++)
{
  // Set random number variable
  int randNum = nums[count]-1;

  std::cout << rainPerMonth[randNum].monthNames << " had " << 
  rainPerMonth[randNum].monthRain    << " inches.\n";
  }

}


int main()
{  
   
   RainStruct structSample[12] = { RainStruct("Jan", 1) , 
                                 RainStruct("Feb", 2) , 
                                 RainStruct("Mar", 3) , 
                                 RainStruct("Apr", 4) , 
                                 RainStruct("May", 5) , 
                                 RainStruct("Jun", 6) , 
                                 RainStruct("Jul", 7) , 
                                 RainStruct("Agu", 8) , 
                                 RainStruct("Sep", 9) , 
                                 RainStruct("Oct", 10) , 
                                 RainStruct("Nov", 11) , 
                                 RainStruct("Dec", 12) , 
                                 }; 
   writeToFile(structSample, 12);
}
```

Output:

```
3 8 11 7 12 1 5 10 6 4 2 9 
Mar had 3 inches.
Agu had 8 inches.
Nov had 11 inches.
Jul had 7 inches.
Dec had 12 inches.
Jan had 1 inches.
May had 5 inches.
Oct had 10 inches.
Jun had 6 inches.
Apr had 4 inches.
Feb had 2 inches.
Sep had 9 inches.
```

You can use your method to write the file

Comment: Credits to [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-an-array-using-stl-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a random number generator will generate the same number twice when you ask for a bunch of random numbers. Asking for 12 random numbers will find some missing and some repeated.

To fix this, you need to first build an array of the month numbers in random order where you make sure that all the months are in it and none are repeated. Otherwise, you will see the effect you mention.

Comment: OP could also verify if the new random value already exists before using it. Also, an "array of month numbers" could work, but if you are already doing that, you could just do an array of the struct

Comment: I appreciate all the help I can get, but for this specific assignment he told us no hard coding. So I HAVE to use a random generator, and he hinted to make the month string and then check if the substring is in the string as we write to a file. This is the site he linked to: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: @Erin -- *So I HAVE to use a random generator* -- If there is a bug in your code, turn off the random number generator and hard code the values.  It makes no sense to try to debug a program that changes every time you run the program.  Once you fix the bug, then turn the random number generator on.

Comment: The instructor is correct. You have to build an array of random numbers from 0 to 11 with no duplicates and no missing. What I did in the past was get a random number and check the array to see if it is already there and if so, go back to get another random number. An alternative method is to build an array with all the months. Then, random select one out and remove it from that array. The next random selection is only from those left.